# Unable to read an xls file properly on R

Tags: r, excel, file-upload

I have a data base on an Excel file and I want to import it on Rstudio
there's the code I entered :

```
library(xlsx)
data=read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\DATA MINING\\BathSoap.xls", sheetName="BSD", header="TRUE")
```

But since the excel file has 2 headers, R is considering the 2nd header as a variable

Help me please

Here's a link to the spreadsheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZAPHmHtsx2l7W0CXyfEBwn2cCsS8GdJwXhxELUoXaI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: SheetName = DM_sheet and not BSD

Answer (score 0):

This should work and read column 3 as variable names.

```
library(xlsReadWrite)
mydat <- read.xls("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\DATA MINING\\BathSoap.xls", colNames = T, sheet = "BSD", type = "data.frame", from = 3, checkNames = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out giving the value header= TRUE instead TRUE in double quotes